# Change row limit on webpart with JS or AngularJs

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, angularjs

I have a webpart wit row limit 9, and a widget that displays me a table with different numbers. I want that table to continue to show me the 9 rows until a date, and after that date to show me 5 rows.

How can I change that value using JavaScript or AngularJS ?

Here is a part of my widget code:

```
<section class="{{::vm.cssClass}}" data-ng-init="vm.cssClass = vm.ClassContainer || 'list_1_container'">
    <a href="{{::vm.moreUrl | replaceNavigationToken}}" class="btn-more" data-ng-if="vm.moreUrl && !vm.moreLabel && vm.HasSeeMoreOption"><span class="tooltip" data-localize="SeeMore">See more</span></a>
    <a href="{{::vm.moreUrl | replaceNavigationToken}}" class="btn-more" data-ng-if="vm.moreUrl && vm.moreLabel && vm.HasSeeMoreOption"><span class="tooltip">{{::vm.moreLabel}}</span></a>
    <a class="btn-user-pref" data-ng-if="vm.UserCustomFilter" data-ng-class="{'push': (vm.moreUrl)}" data-ng-click="vm.showRefinementPopin = true; vm.getRefinersList();"><span class="tooltip">{{::vm.userPrefLabel}}</span></a>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="table" id="tableToday">
            <div class="grid-container-item" data-ng-init="
                vm.itemSizeMobile = vm.itemSizeMobile || 1;
                vm.itemSizeTablet = vm.itemSizeTablet || 1;
                vm.itemSizeDesktop = vm.itemSizeDesktop || 1;
                vm.itemSizeLarge = vm.itemSizeLarge || 1">

                    <div class="item wt-l1-pow0000005369item__background__border ng-repeat-animated item-size-xs-{{::vm.itemSizeMobile}} item-size-sm-{{::vm.itemSizeTablet}} item-size-md-{{::vm.itemSizeDesktop}} item-size-lg-{{::vm.itemSizeLarge}}" 
                    ng-repeat="item in vm.DisplayTemplateData | startFrom: vm.getStartForPaginate(vm.isPaginate,vm.currentPage,vm.numberBeforePaginate) | limitTo: vm.getLimitPaginate(vm.isPaginate,vm.numberBeforePaginate)"> 
                        <div class="container-content">

                            <div class="tableRowDate" data-ng-if=$first>
                                <div class="tableCell">
                                    <h3 class="cellTextTitle" ><span>{{::item.Dia.split('#')[1]}} de {{::item.Mes.split('#')[1]}} de {{::item.Ano.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tableRowFields" data-ng-if=$first>
                                <div class="tableCellType"></div>
                                <div class="tableCellType"><h3 class="cellTextTypeEuribor"><span>Last</span></h3></div>
                                <div class="tableCellType"><h3 class="cellTextTypeEuribor" ><span>Last1</span></h3></div>
                                <div class="tableCellType"><h3 class="cellTextTypeEuribor" ><span>Last2</span></h3></div>
                                <div class="tableCellType"><h3 class="cellTextTypeEuribor" ><span>Last3</span></h3></div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- 1Y Type -->
                            <div data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '1Y'">
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                    <h3 class="cellTextType" id="mytable"><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                    <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div data-ng-if=$even class="tableRowEven" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '1Y'">
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                    <h3 class="cellTextType" id="mytable"><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                    <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span class="cutText">{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tableCellContent20">
                                     <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```